# USB space reduced after making it bootable and unable to recover

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, testdisk

I got a problem here. When I click to Erase Disk in startup Disk Creater in ubuntu 14.04 I get this error:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.AttributeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/service.py", line 707, in _message_cb
    retval = candidate_method(self, *args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/share/usb-creator/usb-creator-helper", line 252, in Format
    partition = table.call_create_partition_sync(0, size, '0x0c', '', no_options, None)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call_create_partition_sync'
```

What Exactly happen was that I create a USB bootable to boot an iso file. Afte it when I pluged it to pc it didn't show in files manager
I tried to repair it with gparted but in Gparted it shows only 64MB (which was 15.6 GB before booting) as unallocated

[image: Image here]

it neither able to add new partition nor partition table
nothing happen when I click  on new partition table

I tried every possible way to repair this but I couldn't 
I also tried with testdisk to change 
I think that the geometry of USB has been corrupted so how to correct geometry of USB drive

[image: Image here]

take a look at image it shows only 3 heads, 43 sectors/track, 1016 cylinders, total 131072 sectors

So I need help to recover full space of 15.6 GB
I am unable to format USB
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The startup disk creator is buggy and has been more or less dropped in 16.04 and replaced with a more simple interface (of the same name).

I would not bother trying to fix it.  Just try to reformat it.  The best thing to do is to pinch your nose and find a windows machine because you tried to do what you could in Linux.  Stick it in and see what it will do, then reformat it the slow way.

Before doing that.  You might try deleting the partition table and then making another one in gparted.  Then try to add a partition and format it.
The tools called disks (in lubuntu 16.04) is better and can slow format too.

When making a new startup disk.  Best to format your disk before and and NOT use startup disk creator to do that (you know that now and that is how I know it too).  There are a few tools to make a startup disk on Ubuntu.  Unetbootin is one.  While you are on a Windows machine, I recommend Live Linux Installer, or Universal USB Creator.